# Editing list in Excel and save to existing Sharepoint list

Tags: list, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, list-form

In Sharepoint 2010 it is possible to export list into excel sheet format, but is it possible to edit list and then export it back to same Sharepoint list?

For example:

1) Sharepoint list (lets say MySharepointList) --> exporting to Excel
2) Make some changes in the Excel sheet.
3) Export changed excel list back to Sharepoint list (i.e MySharepointList).

My purpose, is to use Excel sheet for editing. Because sometimes when there are many columns and we need to edit only one , in Sharepoint we are bound to open whole row for editing. i.e. we cannot click in a column and edit directly in a list.

Comment: I have a very thorough and tested solution for exactly what you're looking for on a related question.
**Answer**: [Import/Copy/Paste Data from Excel into Existing SharePoint List](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/224375/44163).

Answer (score 1):

You can't sync back again, not OOTB. There is a [plugin](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9345) from Microsoft, but then you need to create the list from Excel, and if I remember correctly all fields will be strings. There is an blog post on [sharepoint.microsoft.com](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/Blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=8d9e2a99-f288-47c2-916b-2f32864f7b82&ID=589&Web=5e4647a0-e7d0-4626-b71c-b1ff06402465) on how to use it. What about using DataSheet View, Access or SharePoint Workspaces?

Comment: Datasheet view and access solved my problem.

Comment: @Anders-Aune Actually this is supported, just not easily and has some caveats to it. See my answer linked above. :)